# Can't fetch an array from an api on typescript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, web

For some reason, I try to fetch the complete array of an api but it just doesn't do anything, nothing is changed on the variable that the value SHOULD be going to.

OBS:I'm using Shadcn/ui library and typescript :D

This is my code:

```
import {
  navigationMenuTriggerStyle,
  NavigationMenu,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuContent,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuIndicator,
  NavigationMenuViewport,
} from './components/ui/navigation-menu';
import { divItem } from './components/ui/divItem'
import { Button } from "./components/ui/button"
import { Input } from "./components/ui/input"
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState('');
  let [abilities, setAbilities] = useState(['']);

  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${text.toLowerCase()}`;
  let firstCharacter = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  let restOfName = name.slice(1);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
      try{
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        console.log(responseJson)
        setImageUrl(responseJson.sprites.front_default)
        setName(responseJson.name)
        setWeight(responseJson.weight)
        setAbilities(responseJson.abilities);
      } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
      }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    console.log(imageUrl)
    console.log(firstCharacter + restOfName)
    console.log(abilities)
  }, []);

  /*function fetchData(){
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(info => {
        setImageUrl(info.sprites.front_default)
        setName(info.name)
        setWeight(info.weight)
        jsonData = info.abilities;
        //setAbilities(abilities => [...abilities,data.abilities.ability.name] );
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  */

  return (
    <>
    <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div className="flex justify-between w-1/2">
          <Input id="pokemonInput" placeholder="Pokemon name" className="border rounded w-1/2" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
          <Button onClick={fetchData}>Pesquisar</Button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <img src={imageUrl}id="pokemonImage" className="border rounded min-w-64 min-h-64 max-w-64"/>
        <div className="pl-5">
          <h1>Name: {firstCharacter + restOfName}</h1>
          <h1>Weight: {weight}</h1>
          <NavigationMenu>
            <NavigationMenuList>
              <NavigationMenuItem>
                <NavigationMenuTrigger>Habilidades:</NavigationMenuTrigger>
                <NavigationMenuContent>
                <div className="p-5 min-w-[250px]">
                  <h1>bla</h1>
                  <p>text text text</p>
                </div>
                </NavigationMenuContent>
              </NavigationMenuItem>
            </NavigationMenuList>
          </NavigationMenu>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/script.ts"></script>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

It doesn't get the entire array of the api. It doesn't show an error, nothing, literally nothing happens.

Comment: First of all, you shoult put that `const responde = await fetch(url)` inside of your `try .. catch` block, because it may throw an exception. Furthermore you should check `response.ok` to check if the api returned a non-success (ie >= 400) status code before you try to access your response body. And third, you are initializing `text` with an empty string, so the first call will go to `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon` which doesn't return the structure you are expecting. Use the developer tools to step through your code and see, where the actual behaviour starts to differ from expected one